# How to detect a text file content already alphabetical sorted in Python

Tags: python

I have an existing text file with lines of texts and already in alphanetic sorted. How can I detect in Python programmly that the file already sorted.

example I have file  named input.txt with following lines:

```
"A story book is on table

 By the river, there is a duck

 Meanwhile, let's cooking"
```

what is Python method I can use to check that the lines already sorted alphabetic sorted?

Comment: python has a [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) function that could be helpful. You can sort the file and compare the sorted file to the non-sorted one

Comment: What have you tried? Please share a [mcve]. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, is there any builtin method to detect? instead of compare original file with sorted file?  I did not tried, I just googled but did not find existing method can be used to detect.

Comment: Also, if the text file is large, so compare sorted with non-sorted file may be not feasible. please advice.

Comment: How should punctuations be handled? (comma, period, quotes, etc...)

Answer (score 1):

If you goal is only to tell whether the lines are sorted in order, you can simply iterate through the lines and compare 2 at a time. If everything goes smoothly in alphabetical order until the end, i.e. `line 2 < line 3`, `line 3 < line 4`, `etc.` then the file is sorted, else, it is not.

Here is a quick implementation of that.

```
def is_file_sorted(file_name):

    with open(file_name, 'r') as file:

        # This is the first line
        previous_line = next(file)

        for line in file:

            # Cool, sorted, so far so good
            # Keep going
            if previous_line <= line:
                previous_line = line

            # This line is out of order
            # The file is not sorted
            else:
                return False

        # All the lines are in sorted order
        return True
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('input.txt', 'r') as r:
    for line in sorted(r):
        print(line, end='')
```

this will sort your code!! the problem is that it takes more memory

Comment: thanks all for the help. I tried all solutions suggested, not work for my example text file above. please advice. Also need consider memory usage and efficiency...

Answer (score 0):

```
# Pass in lines from the file
def are_lines_sorted(lines):
    # remove spaces
    lines = [l.strip() for l in lines]
    # do not include empty lines
    lines = [l for l in lines if len(l) > 0]
    # convert all lines to lowercase
    lines = [l.lower() for l in lines]

    return all(l1 <= l2 for l1, l2 in zip(lines, lines[1:]))
```

For the last line:

**1.** `zip(lines, lines[1:])`

This creates(*not really*) a list of pairs of consecutive lines. Like so:

```
[
    (line_1, line_2),
    (line_2, line_3),
    # ...
    (line_n-1, line_n),
]
```

See [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) for more info.

**2.** `for l1, l2 in zip(lines, lines[1:])`

Loop through each pair in #1 and assign them to `l1` and `l2`. This is called [unpacking](https://treyhunner.com/2018/03/tuple-unpacking-improves-python-code-readability/).

**3.** `l1 <= l2 for l1, l2 in zip(lines, lines[1:])`

And for each of the pairings, determine if `l1` is *lexicoghraphically* less than `l2`. This basically creates a list of boolean values for each pair.

**4.** `all(l1 <= l2 for l1, l2 in zip(lines, lines[1:]))`

[all()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) will return true if and only if **all** the bools in #3 are `True`. (i.e. the file is sorted)

Comment: But I tried this solution, even it give False for my sample file mentioned above, do you know why?

Comment: Does the your sample include those quotes?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to know whether the lines are sorted in the file, store the lines into a list iteratively. Now compare the list with it's sorted form (a==sorted(a)) to know whether the file is sorted.

```
##%time 
with open('iris.csv', 'r') as iris:
    a=[]
    for line in iris:
        a.append(line)
    if a==sorted(a):
        print('file is already sorted')
    else:
        print('file is not sorted')
```